Duda sobre Api de google Oauth
Actualmente estoy integrando Oauth de google para usar la API de envío de correo electrónico de gmial en PHP usando una cuenta de espacio de trabajo y siguiendo la guía proporcionada por Google, necesito obtener un token de acceso y luego ese mismo token se puede actualizar si caduca con el refresco_token. Mi pregunta es general. ¿Puede caducar el token? ¿Existe un límite para las actualizaciones de tokens? Porque si envío un correo electrónico no iniciaré sesión en Google cada vez que necesite enviar un correo electrónico desde mi sistema en php, la idea es que el correo electrónico se envíe automáticamente.
Existe alguna forma de que no sea necesario el token inicial? O que se pueda obtener sin iniciar en google ?

En ese caso lo que necesitas es una Cuenta de Servicio, con la cual podrás operar sin intervención del usuario. Pero ten cuidado, guarda a buen seguro el archivo de autorización de esa cuenta, preferiblemente fuera del directorio público del servidor y en una carpeta oculta y con acceso restringido.

Revisa la respuesta a esta pregunta para más detalles. Allí explica cómo crear la Cuenta de Servicio, descargar el archivo, etc. El ejemplo era para usar la API de Google Analytics, puede que para tu caso sea más sencillo, y no tengas que ejecutar los pasos propios de Google Analytics (paso 1.3). Puede que algunas cosas hayan variado desde entonces. Por ejemplo, GSuite, ya no existe, ahora se llama Workspace, pero los pasos siguen siendo más o menos los mismos.

@A.Cedano Pero una cuenta de servicio funcionara igual que la cuenta de google normal ? Osea la idea de usar el api es que cuando enviamos el correo sale como remitente la cuenta de donde se habilita el Oauth, aparte de eso una cuenta de servicio solo dan como una dirección de correo

La cuenta de Servicio actúa como la cuenta (de correo) que la ha creado, según los permisos que des a esa cuenta (de Servicio) y las APIs que autorices. En este caso debes autorizar la API de Gmail y podrás enviar correos en nombre de esa cuenta (de correo). Supongamos un script PHP que se activa de forma periódica, podrás enviar correos desde ese script sin que el usuario tenga que poner sus credenciales.

Si quieres poder enviar correos, o hacer otras operaciones más avanzadas, sin necesidad de intervención del usuario, puedes crear una Cuenta de Servicio en tu proyecto de Google Cloud y luego delegar autoridad de todo el dominio a esa cuenta de servicio.
Vas a necesitar realizar varias operaciones, sea del lado de Google (tanto en Cloud Console como en Workspace) sea del lado del servidor.
Vamos a explicarlo.
1. Del lado de Google
a. En Cloud Console
Tienes que iniciar sesión en Google Cloud Console con tu usuario de Workspace y crear el proyecto si no existe. Y luego dentro del proyecto crear una Cuenta de Servicio. Una vez creada la Cuenta de Servicio deberás crear una clave en formato JSON, siguiendo los pasos que se indican en la documentación de Google. En ese momento se descargará un archivo JSON con las claves. Deberás guardar ese archivo en un lugar muy seguro de tu servidor, luego lo necesitarás para el código PHP.
También, en ese proyecto, tienes que habilitar la API de Gmail, que es el servicio con el que vas a trabajar. Si fueras a trabajar con otros servicios de Google, debes habilitar sus APIs.
b. En Workspace
Tienes que abrir la consola de Admin y allí ir a la opción Seguridad > Controles de API > Delegación de todo el dominio.
Donde dice Clientes de API pulsa en el botón Añadir nuevo.

Se abrirá el siguiente modal donde deberás poner el ID de cliente, los permisos de OAuth y pulsar en AUTORIZAR para confirmar. La casilla que dice Sobrescribir ID de cliente actual no hay que marcarla:


ID del Cliente: Ese valor lo obtendrás en Cloud Console. Está en la página donde se muestra la Cuenta de Servicio, en el panel de detalles, a la derecha, una opción que se llama ID de cliente de OAuth 2. Copias ese valor y lo pegas en el campo del modal que te pide el ID del cliente.



Permisos de OAuth (separados por comas): Es para indicar los permisos que quieres dar a ese cliente. Como bien se indica, si quieres otorgar varios permisos, los pones separados por coma. Consulta aquí para ver los tipos de permisos y lo que se puede hacer con ellos.


IMPORTANTE: Otorga siempre permisos adecuados a lo que quieres hacer. Por ejemplo, no des el permiso
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify si lo único que quieres
es enviar mensajes, en cuyo caso, bastará con el permiso
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose.


AUTORIZAR. Finalmente, pulsa en el botón AUTORIZAR para guardar los cambios.

Ahora deberás ver en tu pantalla de Admin la autorización.


IMPORTANTE: Cuando autorizas un cliente o cambias los permisos esto puede tomar un tiempo para propagarse, Según Google puede ser de
aproximadamente 24 horas. En mi caso la autorización se reconoció en
cuestión de minutos (es una cuenta de Workspace con un solo usuario).

Cuando los cambios se propaguen, ya podrás preparar tu entorno de servidor. Para cuando termines los pasos que ahora explico, es posible que tus cambios estén propagados.
2. Entorno de servidor
Para el caso de PHP, lo mejor es usar Composer. Con él puedes instalar fácilmente la biblioteca cliente de Google, ejecutando simplemente esto en la consola de tu servidor:
composer require google/apiclient:^2.15.0

Haciendo esto, tendrás en el directorio vendor todos los archivos necesarios para trabajar con cualquier API de Google. Si no usas Composer tendrías que hacerlo a mano, lo cual sería harto tedioso. Si ya tienes instalada tu biblioteca cliente, ignora lo dicho.
Pero atención. El anterior comando composer require te agregará todos los servicios de Google. Por eso, conviene que pongas sólo aquellos servicios con los que vayas a trabajar, tal y como indican el Github, eso se hace modificando el archivo composer.json que estará en el root de tu servidor, allí buscas un apartado extra (si no existe lo creas) y pones los servicios que quieres. Por ejemplo, si vas a trabajar con Gmail, con Sheets y con Drive. Igualmente, dentro del apartado scripts tienes que agregar eso: "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup". Si no hay un apartado scripts lo creas.
El archivo se verá así más o menos:
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.15.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Sheets",
            "Calendar",
            "Gmail"
        ]
    },
}

Luego ejecutas este comando para borrar todos los servicios de Google que instaló Composer (aunque en el enlace pasan sólo el parámetro -r, conviene pasarle -rf, para que haga un borrado recursivo de los archivos, sino te preguntará cada vez si quieres borrar o no:
rm -rf vendor/google/apiclient-services

Y finalmente, para que te incluya solamente los servicios que indicaste en extra, actualizas ejecutando este comando:
composer update


IMPORTANTE: Deja en composer.json todo aquello que no tenga que ver con Google. Lo digo porque podrías estarlo ya usando para otras
cosas en tu servidor y si lo quitas esas cosas se quitarán cuando
ejecutes el comando anterior.

Cuando la biblioteca cliente esté lista, ahora puedes usarla para manejar mensajes de Gmail.
Veamos un código de ejemplo para enviar un mensaje. Trabajaremos con clases para tener el código mejor organizado. Es importante que la biblioteca cliente y el archivo con las claves estén en las rutas correctas y que las mismas se indiquen correctamente en el código para que funcione.
require_once '/ruta-correcta-de/vendor/autoload.php';

//...

/*
  Función para obtener el cliente 
  La ruta del archivo debe ser correcta y
  el archivo debió haber sido pasado al servidor
*/

function getClient()
{
    $domainUser="usuario@dominio.com"; //Sin esto no funcionará
    $jsonFile = 'una-carpeta-muy-segura/TU-ARCHIVO-DE-CLAVES.json';

    $client=new Client(['credentials' => $jsonFile]);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose");
    $client->setSubject($domainUser);
    return $client;
}


/*
  Clase para construir los mensajes y enviarlos 
*/
class EMailMessage
{
    private $name;
    private $from;
    private $to;
    private $subject;
    private $body;

    public function __construct($name,$from,$to,$subject,$body)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->from=$from;
        $this->to=$to;
        $this->subject=$subject;
        $this->body=$body;
    }

    public function send($gmail)
    {
      try{

        $rawMessage = "From: {$this->name} <{$this->from}> \r\n";
        $rawMessage .= "To: <$this->to>\r\n";
        $rawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . "?=\r\n";
        $rawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $rawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $rawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
        $rawMessage .= "$this->body\r\n";
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($rawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
        $send=$gmail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
        echo "Mensaje enviado";
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

/*
  Un uso contextual cualquiera
*/
$client = getClient();
$service = new Gmail($client);
$name="Nombre Remitente";
$from="quien@envia.com";
$to="el@destinatario.com";
$subject="Prueba de API PHP con Client Service";
$body="<p>Lorem <b>ipsum</b></p>";
$eMailMessage=new EMailMessage($name,$from,$to,$subject,$body);
$eMailMessage->send($service);

El código manda el mensaje correctamente:


¿Puede caducar el token?
El access token expira.
Debes implementar OAuth versión 2.0, el access token tiene un tiempo de vida limitado el cual puedes configurar
Establece un tiempo de vencimiento prolongado para los tokens de OAuth
, pero puedes utilizar el refresh token para obtener un nuevo access token sin requerir que el usuario vuelva a iniciar sesión.
A diferencia del access token, el refresh token no caduca fácilmente, aunque este puede ser revocado o invalidado por el usuario si es que no se utiliza por un tiempo prolongado.
¿Existe un límite para las actualizaciones de tokens?
Puedes usar el refresh token varias veces para obtener nuevos access tokens y una vez que estás autenticado, puedes enviar correos sin iniciar sesión cada vez.
Importante: No es posible evitar el primer proceso de inicio de sesión para obtener el refresh token, pero luego no es necesario repetirlo.
